# Corrector of the orthography!

Tags: spelling

I have a middle level in English language, and I am writing my thesis using Texmaker, i would like to know how to have a good corrector so that I don't do mistakes in orthography?

Thank you to telling me the steps to do that!

Comment: You can use language tool with LaTeX (although you probably need to switch to [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org)): http://wiki.languagetool.org/checking-la-tex-with-languagetool

Comment: TeX Studio is the best LaTeX editor ever. Period.

Comment: I do not consider this really a Latex-related question. However, if you want my advice, use the corrector of your favorite environment, especially Overleaf (online) or TeXstudio. It also works for me to copy the text into a word document and check aspects related to the syntax.